# Why is my JavaFX program using fxml getting the error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.VBox"?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a program that was created with java swing, but I hit a point where using it without much online help with issues I ran into so I am starting to learn JavaFX and using fxml for the gui, so I tried to create the main window in JavaFX code. With only code, I was able to make it appear how I wanted. I then decided to switch it to fxml, so I created the fxml file, added the code in my java file to load it, but when i ran the program, I keep getting the error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.VBox", or the same for HBox, depending on which I used. I tried figuring it out myself, also tried chatGpt, but but I couldn't find a solution. What confuses me is that when I first created the JavaFX project in VS Code, it used VBox in the fxml, but worked fine. I have copied all code that that used, just changed the fxml nodes.
For context, here is the module file, my code, and the fxml file.

```
module gearworks {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens gearworks to javafx.fxml;
    exports gearworks;
}
```

```
package gearworks;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private BorderPane root;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gearworks/BaseGui.fxml"));
        try {
            root = loader.load();
            System.out.println((root == null) + " root is null");
            if (root == null) {
                throw new IOException("FXML root is null");
                
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1300, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Gui");
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> primaryStage.close());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

```
<?fxml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="gearworks.App">
    <top>
        <HBox>
            <Children>
                <Button text="button 1" />
                <Label text="label 1" />
                <Button text="button 2" />
            </Children>
        </HBox>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Also, here is the directory setup
src
|-- main
|-- java
|   |-- gearworks
|       |-- App.java
|
|-- resources
|-- gearworks
|-- BasicGui.fxml

This is just the simple version of the program I am trying to make, I just kept shrinking the design, hoping that at some point it would work and I would go from there, but it never did.

This was the original code that worked before trying to use fxml, minus the imports

```
public class App extends Application {

    

    private BorderPane root;
    private HBox openFilePanel, saveFilePanel, dataManipulationPanel, jobSelectionPanel, displayPanel, bottomPanel,
            jobFilterPanel;
    private VBox bottom;
    private Label openFilePathLabel, saveFilePathLabel, currentJob;
    private Button chooseOpenFile, updateBidders, chooseSaveFolder, saveExcel, filterJobs, addPricing, previousJob,
            nextJob;

    private final Font TITLE_FONT = Font.font("Monospaced", FontWeight.BOLD, 50);
    private final Font FONT = Font.font("Monospaced", FontWeight.NORMAL, 16);

    private final String css = this.getClass().getResource("Element_Styles.css").toExternalForm();
    // Dark Theme Colors
    private final Color PRIMARY_FONT_COLOR = Color.rgb(0, 179, 189);
    private final Color SECONDARY_FONT_COLOR = Color.rgb(55, 136, 186);
    private final Color TERTIARY_FONT_COLOR = Color.rgb(192, 155, 82);
    private final Color QUATERNARY_FONT_COLOR = Color.rgb(61, 86, 123);

    private final Color PRIMARY_BACKGROUND = Color.rgb(13, 21, 33);
    private final Color SECONDARY_BACKGROUND = Color.rgb(16, 26, 41);

    private final Color TITLE_FONT_COLOR = TERTIARY_FONT_COLOR;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        root = new BorderPane();

        openFilePanel = new HBox();
        openFilePanel.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        openFilePanel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        openFilePathLabel = new Label("File Path:  ");
        openFilePathLabel.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        openFilePathLabel.setFont(FONT);
        openFilePathLabel.setTextFill(QUATERNARY_FONT_COLOR);

        chooseOpenFile = new Button("Open Bidding File...");

        updateBidders = new Button("Add Update Bidders");
        updateBidders.setDisable(true);

        // Add spacer to push the label to the left
        Region ofpSpacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(ofpSpacer, Priority.ALWAYS);

        openFilePanel.getChildren().addAll(chooseOpenFile, openFilePathLabel, ofpSpacer, updateBidders);

        saveFilePanel = new HBox();
        saveFilePanel.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        saveFilePanel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        saveFilePathLabel = new Label("Directory Path:  ");
        saveFilePathLabel.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        saveFilePathLabel.setFont(FONT);
        saveFilePathLabel.setTextFill(QUATERNARY_FONT_COLOR);

        chooseSaveFolder = new Button("Choose a Save Folder...");
        saveExcel = new Button("Export Excel File");

        // Add spacer to push the label to the left
        Region sfpSpacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(sfpSpacer, Priority.ALWAYS);

        saveFilePanel.getChildren().addAll(chooseSaveFolder, saveFilePathLabel, sfpSpacer, saveExcel);

        dataManipulationPanel = new HBox();
        dataManipulationPanel.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10));

        filterJobs = new Button("Confirm Selected Jobs");
        addPricing = new Button("Add Pricing to Jobs");
        jobFilterPanel = new HBox();
        jobFilterPanel.setSpacing(10);
        jobFilterPanel.getChildren().addAll(filterJobs, addPricing);

        previousJob = new Button("<< Previous Job");
        currentJob = new Label("(00/00)");
        currentJob.setFont(FONT);
        currentJob.setTextFill(QUATERNARY_FONT_COLOR);
        nextJob = new Button("Next Job >>");
        jobSelectionPanel = new HBox();
        jobSelectionPanel.setSpacing(10);
        jobSelectionPanel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox.setHgrow(jobSelectionPanel, Priority.ALWAYS); // Expand to fill available space
        jobSelectionPanel.getChildren().addAll(previousJob, currentJob, nextJob);

        dataManipulationPanel.getChildren().addAll(jobFilterPanel, jobSelectionPanel);

        bottom = new VBox();
        bottom.getChildren().addAll(dataManipulationPanel, saveFilePanel);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Gui");

        root.setTop(openFilePanel);

        Label titleLabel = new Label("BIDDING PROGRAM");
        titleLabel.setFont(TITLE_FONT);
        titleLabel.setTextFill(TITLE_FONT_COLOR);

        Label descriptionLabel = new Label("Click \"Open Bidding File\" To Get Started");
        descriptionLabel.setFont(FONT);
        descriptionLabel.setTextFill(SECONDARY_FONT_COLOR);

        VBox displayBox = new VBox(titleLabel, descriptionLabel);
        displayBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        displayBox.setSpacing(10);
        displayBox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(SECONDARY_BACKGROUND, null, null)));

        root.setCenter(displayBox);

        root.setBottom(bottom);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1300, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> primaryStage.close());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I started with a large gui design with more code, which didn't work, so what I tried was to make the code as small as possible, ending up the simple program said before. I expected that at some point, I would take a line of code that it didn't like, and then systematically adding it back until I found the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The JavaFX layout classes, such as `HBox`, `VBox`, and `BorderPane`, etc., are in the `javafx.scene.layout` package (not the `javafx.scene.control` package).

Hence when the `FXMLLoader` encounters `javafx.scene.control.HBox` it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`, because there is no such class.

Replace

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.HBox ?>
```

with

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox ?>
```

in the FXML file.